# How to move elements depending on what there is in the vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to know how I can move elements from one vector to another depending on which element there is in the other vector. For example let's say I have 2 vectors. One is empty and the other has integers in it. How do I write the if and else statement if I want to move the number 2 if there is a number 2 in the other vector.

```
int main() {

vector <int> myvec {};
vector <int> newvec {1,2,3,4,5};

if () {

}  

else if () {




    }

displaypoints(newvec);
displaypoints(myvec);
```

The code above is like what I was saying. If there is a number 2 in the newvec vector then move it to myvec vector. If there is no number 2 in the newvec vector then move the number 3 instead. What would the statements be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::find()` to know if there is 2 in some range in `newVec`, then insert 2 if there is a 2 and 3 otherwise

```
if (auto it = std::find(newVec.begin(), newVec.end(), 2); it != newVec.end()) {//c++17 feature
    myVec.push_back(*it);
}
else myVec.push_back(3);
```

`std::find` returns an iterator to the first found element equal to the specified value or an iterator to the position next to the last element in your range otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I think this example can solve what you said:
'When there is number 2 in vector1 then move it to vector2.'
'Otherwise move number 3.'

```
bool move_vec(vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2, int x) {
    int cnt = 0;
    vector<int>::iterator it = v1.begin();
    while (it != v1.end()) {
        if (*it == x) {
            ++cnt;
            it = v1.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    v2.insert(v2.end(), cnt, x);
    return cnt != 0;
}
vector<int>a = { 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 }, b = { 1,1,1 };
int main() {
    if (!move_vec(a, b, 2))
        move_vec(a, b, 3);
    return 0;
}
```